# What is the difference between host created with vmotion enabled and normal one

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vmotion

I want to know what is the difference between hosts created with vmotion enabled and normal one (Apart from live migration).

How does it work? any directions will be appreciated.

Comment: One has a license that supports vMotion and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Umm, pretty simple:

The one with VMotion enabled has the necessary network and vmkernel configuration and infrastructure necessary to support VMotion. The other one lacks this configuration.

Comment: Yeah, this + the license that joequerty mentioned.